# Checking for empty queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to confirm is this the right way to check for empty queryset, and if it is why am I having a UNIQUE constraint error.

```
syn_check= Synonym.objects.filter(MD.objects.get(**filter_dict), synonym_type=Stype.objects.filter(description=values.capitalize().strip()), synonym_name=key)
if not syn_check:
    print 'unavailable synonym', key, values
    syn = Synonym()
    syn.synonym_type=Stype.objects.filter(description=values.capitalize().strip()
    syn.synonym_name = key.strip()
    syn.save()
```

Am I doing anything that is weird? I also used `if not syn_check.count()` and I had the same problem.

Here is the traceback :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/project/PycharmProjects/project/project/management/commands/back_populate_data.py", line 53, in handle
    loaded_syn = data_loaded_syn4_pubchem(synonym_decoded, filter_dict)
  File "/home/project/PycharmProjects/project/project/lookup_data.py", line 203, in data_loaded_syn4_pubchem
    mol_syn_ob.save()
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 698, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 731, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 921, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: project_synonym.molecule_id, project_synonym.synonym_name, project_synonym.synonym_type_id
```

Thanks

Comment: Doing `Synonym.objects.filter(MD.objects.filter())` looks wrong, you shouldn't be passing a queryset as an argument to filter. What are you trying to do there, and how does `MD` relate to `Synonym`? The actual check `if not syn_check:` is ok. However `.count()` would be more efficient, and `.exists()` even better, since you don't need to access the objects in the queryset.

Comment: The MD is the parent table and the Synonym is the related table of the MD.  It has worked with out a problem in other part of the codes. I am not sure why it is a problem here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the other places of your code as well, even if it's not throwing an error. The `filter()` method takes [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) as arguments, or [keyword arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters). It doesn't make sense to pass a queryset as an argument, and I'm still not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I took this onboard and redefined to `syn_check = Synonym.objects.filter(mol=id, synonym_type=syn_type,
                                                           synonym_name=key)`. And that works great thanks.

Comment: Great! I've added my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking the queryset as you are doing is fine.

```
if not syn_check:
```

However, it is not as efficent as it could be, you are loading all the objects from the database, when all you want to know is whether the queryset is empty or not.

It would be better to use `count()`,

```
if not syn_check.count():
```

and even better to use `exists()`

```
if not syn_check.exists():
```

The problem in your code is where you define the queryset

```
syn_check = Synonym.objects.filter(MD.objects.get(**filter_dict), synonym_type=Stype.objects.filter(description=values.capitalize().strip()), synonym_name=key)
```

The `filter()` method accepts either [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) as args, or [keyword arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters). It doesn't make sense to pass the model instance from `MD.objects.get(...)` as a positional argument.