# Check results of model object query in django

Tags: python, django

Using:

[Checking for empty queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523758/checking-for-empty-queryset)

I have the following code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    currency_value_in_dollars = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_name


class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_pass = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    join_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name


class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_amount = models.FloatField()
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    transaction_currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

views.py:

```
def get_latest_currency(self):
    """
    Return most up to date value
    """
    filtered_currency = Currency.objects.filter(
            currency_value_in_dollars_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1]

    if not filtered_currency:
        # No objects yet; fetch currencies
        update_coins_table()
```

Even though I have no entries update_coins_table() is not executed. Why doesn't filter work as expected? (contain the results of the query?)

When the if is reached, the following error is thrown:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "manage_crypto_currency_currency" does not exist
LINE 1: ...y_currency"."currency_value_in_dollars_date" FROM "manage_cr...
```

I have no idea how the relation manage_crypto_currency_currency was created since that string is not even in the code.

It most likely has to do with the migration:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.3 on 2020-11-18 17:58

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Currency',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('currency_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('currency_value_in_dollars', models.FloatField()),
                ('currency_value_in_dollars_date', models.DateField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('user_name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('user_pass', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('join_date', models.DateField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Transaction',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('transaction_type', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('transaction_amount', models.FloatField()),
                ('transaction_date', models.DateField()),
                ('transaction_currency', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='manage_crypto_currency.currency')),
                ('transaction_users', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='manage_crypto_currency.user')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

But why does django create 'manage_crypto_currency_currency' since it's obviosuly not a relation.

Running migrations:

```
(venv) C:\>python manage.py makemigrations manage_crypto_currency
Migrations for 'manage_crypto_currency':
  manage_crypto_currency\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Currency
    - Create model User
    - Create model Transaction

(venv) C:\>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, manage_crypto_currency, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying manage_crypto_currency.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the record exists or not you can use the `exists()` method. See below code:

```
def get_latest_currency(self):
    """
    Return most up to date value
    """
    filtered_currency = Currency.objects.filter(
            currency_value_in_dollars_date__lte=timezone.now()
        )

    if not filtered_currency.exists():
        update_coins_table()
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Internal Server Error: /get_currency/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\django\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "manage_crypto_currency_currency" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "manage_crypto_currency_currency" WHE...

Comment: Delete all the migrations and reset the database and then again migrate it.

Comment: Edited question; it seems that was it

Comment: Yup! Got it. Finally :P